# Prove the real radical is an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

How does one prove that the **real** radical of an ideal $I$ is an ideal. (NOT to be confused the radical of an ideal)

Consider $f,h$ in the real radical. both have a corresponding integers $m,n$ and a sequence of functions such that its sum of squares are in the ideal $I$. in other words, $f^{2m},g^{2n}$ can be written as a sum of squared functions plus a function in ideal I. consider the expansion of $(f+h)^{mn}$. the goal is to show that this expansion can be written as a sum of squared functions plus a sum of functions in ideal $I$. But when you expand it, this is not at all clear. even if you consider $(f+h)^{m+n}$, its not clear either

Comment: @DietrichBurde where in the wikipedia page does it give the proof?

Comment: In the cited Marshall paper.

Comment: @DietrichBurde are you sure you understand my question correctly though? I want to show that the real radical of an ideal satisfies all the properties of an ideal. I am not interested in showing that the real radical of I is equal to I.

Comment: Yes, it is clear that you want to show that  $\sqrt[\Bbb R]{I}$ is an ideal of the ring. The other claim [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4364066/real-radical-ideal-which-is-not-prime?noredirect=1&lq=1) is that $f^n\in \sqrt[\Bbb R]{I}$ implies $f\in \sqrt[\Bbb R]{I}$. It is also explained in, say, [these notes](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjFz8X7-PT9AhVS_7sIHSdKDW4QFnoECAoQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uni-konstanz.de%2F~kuhlmann%2FLehre%2FSS10-PosPoly%2FSkripts%2FPPSS10Lect-4.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0xi74f2WeS-KboEBGz6Cco).

Comment: @DietrichBurde unfortunately, I have checked Marshall's paper already and he does not give any such proof. He defines the real radical on page 177, defines some properties about it, but does not show that it satisfies all the properties of an ideal.

Comment: So why do you think it is an ideal? What have you tried so far to prove it?

Comment: @DietrichBurde consider f,h in real radical. both have a corresponding integers m,n and a sequence of functions such that its sum of squares are in the ideal I. in other words, $f^{2m}$,$g^{2n}$ can be written as a sum of squared functions plus a function in ideal I. consider the expansion of $(f+h)^{mn}$. the goal is to show that this expansion can be written as a sum of squared functions plus a sum of functions in ideal I. But when you expand it, this is not at all clear. even if you consider $(f+h)^{m+n}$, its not clear either

Comment: You should put this work in your post with an [edit].

Comment: @KReiser so are you going to help me?

Comment: If you put it in your post, maybe, depending on what other stuff I have to do. But you should still put your work in your post - questions without any supporting context don't meet our [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and are likely to be downvoted and closed. In particular, your post has a downvote and multiple close votes as of the time of writing this comment. A closed question will not receive any answers until it's reopened, so your chances of getting help here from anyone will be improved by improving your post.

Comment: @KReiser you are correct. I have updated my post. I would really appreciate your help on this as my colleagues and have been discussing this problem for days without any success

Answer (score 3):

$A$ is a commutative ring, $\sum A^2$ denotes the set of elements that are sums of squares.  The real radical of a set $I$ is defined is $\{a \in A \mid \exists m \in \mathbb{N}, \sigma \in \sum A^2, a^{2m} + \sigma \in I \}$.

We want to show that when $I$ has the structure of an ideal, so too does the real radical of $I$.

I will outline an easy way to prove that the real radical is an ideal in any commutative ring.

**Step 1**: Check that the real radical of $I$ is closed under scalar multiplication whenever $I$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

Let $c \in A$ and $a$ in the real radical of $I$.
Find $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\sigma \in \sum A^2$ such that $a^{2m} + \sigma \in I$.

Set $\sigma_c = \sum (c^{m}a_{i})^2 \in \sum A^2$.  Check that $(ca)^{2m} + \sigma_c \in I$.

**Step 2**: If $b \in I$ and $a$ is in the real radical of $I$.  Then $a + b$ is in the real radical of $I$.

By assumption $a^{2m} + \sigma \in I$ and then $c := (a + b)^{2m} - a^{2m}$ is in $I$ because it is divisible by $b$.  Thus $(a + b)^{2m} + \sigma = a^{2m} + c + \sigma \in I$.

**Step 3** Observe that $\sum A^2$ is a subsemiring of $A$ (most importantly it is closed under addition and multiplication) and it contains the image of each positive integer.

**Step 4** The real radical of the real radical of $I$ is equal to the real radical of $I$.

Suppose that $a$ is in the real radical of the real radical of $I$.  Then find $\sigma \in \sum A^2$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^{2m} + \sigma$ is in the real radical of $I$.  Then find $\sigma' \in \sum A^2$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(a^{2m} + \sigma)^{2n} + \sigma' \in I$.  Use the observation in Step 3 to see that $(a^{2m} + \sigma)^{2n} - {a^{2m}}^{2n} \in \sum A^2$.

Finally we will address
**Closure under addition** when $I$ is an ideal.

Suppose that $a,b$ are both in the real radical of $I$.  Suppose that $c:= a^{2m} + \sigma \in I$.  Note that $d := (a+ b)^{2m} - a^{2m}$ is divisible by $b$.  By Step $1$, $d$ is in the real radical of $I$.  Now $(a + b)^{2m} + \sigma = c + d$ is the sum of an element of $I$ and an element in the real radical.  By Step $2$, $c + d$ is in the real radical of $I$.  But this shows that $(a + b)^{2m} + \sigma$ is in the real radical of $I$.  Hence $a+ b$ is in the real radical of the real radical of $I$.  By step 4, $a+ b$ is in the real radical of $I$.

Comment: Small nitpick: in step 3 you say "$\sum A^2$ is a subring of $A$" but I guess you mean it's closed under addition and multiplication (since it doesn't need to have additive inverses if $-1 \not \in \sum A^2$)

Comment: thanks and fixed.  it is only a 'subrig'!

Comment: One more remark: this also shows that if $a, b$ are in the real radical, then so is $a - b$ (so it really is an ideal)

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ and $g$ are in the real radical of an ideal $I$, there are $n,m\in\mathbb N$ and sums of squares $\sigma,\tau$ such that
$$f^{2m}+\sigma,g^{2n}+\tau\in I.$$
The binomial theorem ensures that
$$(f+g)^{2m+2n}=f^{2m}p+g^{2n}q$$
for some $p,q$, thus
$$2(f+g)^{2m+2n}+f^{2m}(p^2+1)+g^{2n}(q^2+1)=f^{2m}(p+1)^2+g^{2n}(q+1)^2.$$
Since $I$ is an ideal, it follows that
$$(f+g)^{2m+2n}+\underbrace{(f+g)^{2m+2n}+f^{2m}(p^2+1)+g^{2n}(q^2+1)+\sigma(p+1)^2+\tau(q+1)^2}_{\text{sum of squares}}=(f^{2m}+\sigma)(p+1)^2+(g^{2n}+\tau)(q+1)^2\in I,$$
i.e., $f+g$ is in the real radical.

Comment: The third and fourth line seem to be missing a few terms: $2(f+g)^{2m+2n}+f^{2m}(p^2{\color{red}+1})+g^{2n}(q^2{\color{red}+1})=f^{2m}(p+1)^2+g^{2n}(q+1)^2$

Comment: Ah, you are right, thanks.